# SugarCRM/SuiteCRM Api Login redirect

Tags: php, session, crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am using the v4_1 Rest API from Sugar/Suite CRM to login:

http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/Web_Services/Examples/REST/PHP/Logging_In/

I have taken this php code and created a loginAuth.php script and put the credentials for a user in it...  It works and returns me a session id...

My problem now is I don't know what to do with the session id I get back...  I try to redirect the main page, but it takes me back to the login screen...

Workflow:

1. call loginAuth.php (validate/get sessionid)
2. if valid session, redirect to index.php?module=Home&action=index

But it's just taking me to the main page...

Any ideas on how I can bypass the login form when using the API?

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: hello I am having the same issue. Are you still using the REST API? I can't get the session id back after adding the credentials, is there any config that you used?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. There are two cookies that set:

```
PHPSESSID
```

and

```
MSID
```

but you have to send MSID to the index.php page FIRST...  So simply add this line to the bottom of the php script:

```
header("Location: http://{site_url}/index.php?MSID=$session_id");
```

and it will bypass the login.